# ASP Button - run OnClick after OnClientClick dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a page with a button on it. I need a dialog to be opened when user click it (I'm using JQuery UI).

Dialog has two buttons: run server code or close dialog.

The problem is that dialog could wait for user action only if OnClientClick returns false, but in this case OnClick won't fire.

So far I have this code, dialog window closes a moment after it opens.
Any ideas?

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 240,
        width: 440,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "RUN SERVER PART": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            },
            "CLOSE": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

function shwindow() {
    if ($("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open"))
        return true;
    else
     return false;
}
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="aspbt" runat="server" OnClientClick="if(!shwindow()) return false;"    OnClick="aspbt_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function shwindow() {
  if($("#dialog-confirm").dialog("isOpen")){
    return true;
  }      
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Check dialog is visible or not by using 'isOpen'. Based on that return true or false.

**Update:**

```
if($(".ui-dialog").is(":visible")){

}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fprvt2pq/

Comment: the idea is to run OnClick event after OnClientClick, not just show modal window...

Answer (score 0):

managed to postpone OnClick event by setting FALSE as a return value and calling postback:

`"RUN SERVER PART": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            __doPostBack($("[id$=aspbt]")[0].name, '');
            return true;
         }`

I don't really like this solution so maybe someone has a better one...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="aspbt" runat="server" OnClientClick="return shwindow();"    OnClick="aspbt_Click" />
```

Comment: It would help if you explained how your code works / what was wrong. Just a snippet is not a good answer in most cases.

Comment: you're right but answer is light,@Anton write a function that return `true' or `false` and want to do postback if function return `true`,OK, just in `OnClientClick` we check the return value, if it was true the PostBack will execute.